# Zabbix agent is not available alert in a zabbix proxy

Tags: proxy, alert, monitoring, zabbix

Using Zabbix version 4.2.6 I get the alert **Zabbix agent is not available** with a zabbix proxy that i have properly installed,configured and registered. I tried to reboot the proxy machine, several times but nothing works right or at least , the alert still stays on the dashboard.

The ip by which the proxy is registered is the loopback one: 127.0.0.1.

Would it be possible to be an error of the agent

The operating system of the zabbix proxy that is being monitored is Ubuntu Server 18.04

Comment: do you find errors in the zabbix server log, in the zabbix proxy log and/or in the zabbix agent log? They might be very helpful and often point to the cause.

Comment: How can I check the logs of the zabbix agent? Or the ones of the zabbix proxy?

Comment: How can I check the logs of the zabbix agent of the proxy?

Comment: Look in /var/log/zabbix/ or wherever you configured the logs to be